# Refactoring a React component's render method results in errors

Tags: reactjs

```
class Widget extends React.Component  {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <p>Hi</p>;
  }
}
```

Works great. Hooray! But this (#2)...

```
class Widget extends React.Component  {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getElement() {
    return <p>Hi</p>
  }

  render() {
    let Thing = this.getElement();
    return <Thing/>;
  }
}
```

Throws

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `Widget`.

and this (#3)...

```
  render() {
    let Thing = this.getElement();
    return {Thing};
  }
```

throws

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Thing}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I figured out I can use it like this (#4)...

```
  render() {
    let Thing = this.getElement();
    return <>
      {Thing}
    </>;
  }
```

But I don't understand why #2 and #3 don't work. What is going on here?

Comment: Given that `getElement` returns an element, why are you trying to use that as the *name* of an element? `{Thing}` *outside* JSX is *object shorthand*, the same as `{ Thing: Thing }`, how would that help? Why don't you just `return this.getElement()`?

Comment: This is a simplified scenario. My end goal is to conditionally use multiple instances of `this.getElement()` to build up the `render` method. But I'm a noob and I don't know if that even makes sense in a React environment (I'm suspecting it might not).

Comment: Then rather than `getElement` you probably want `getComponent`, which will `return () => <p>Hi</p>` (i.e. a very simple function-based component); then your original example `<Thing />` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for #2 it is quite simple, internally any `<E ...></E>` or `<E ... />` is implemented as `React.createElement(E, ...)` where E is of type Component (either functional or class, or alternatievly string for HTML elements). `React.createElement` returns type React.Node. Therefore here

```
    let Thing = this.getElement();
    return <Thing/>;
```

is problem - `this.getElement()` returns Node, but <... /> expects `Thing` to be Component - this causes the error you show.

For #3 problem lies in how syntax of react and newer ECMAScript versions work - in JSX, any block of React components is surrounded by root element (`<>` in #4 or `<p>` in `getElement`). But newer ECMAScript (I'm not sure about version) introduces shorthand for object definition - where this

```
   const prop = 'foo';
   const obj = { prop };
```

is equal to

```
   const prop = 'foo';
   const obj = { prop: prop };
```

because in  #3 you have no root element, syntax `{Thing}` is treated as JavaScript object and yield `{Thing: <p>...</p>}`, but render should return Node, means error.

Depends on your case either do

```
   render() {
     if (someCondition) {
        return this.renderSomething();
     }

     return this.renderDefault()
   }
```

or alternatievly if you need some common wrapping element, you should go with method #4

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks!